# How to get values from JSON webservice with 2 objects in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I'm new in Angular 2 and I'm quite lost. I have a JSON web service responding to /rest/alertsDashboard. It returns something like:

```
{
  "total": {
    "totalOperations": 2573,
    "totalOperationsAlert": 254,
    "totalOperationsRisk": 34
  },
  "alerts": [
      {
        codAlert: "L1",
        description: "Alert 1",
        value: 1
      },
      {
        codAlert: "L2",
        description: "Alert 2",
        value: 2
      },
      ...
  ]
}
```

So I defined a DashboardComponent component and a AlertDashboardService service. I would like, for example, to display totalOperations and totalOperationsAlert. I don't know if I'm doing it in a correct way.

In dashboard.component.ts I have:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  template: `
    <p>{{totalAlertsDashboard.totalOperations}}</p>
    <p>{{totalAlertsDashboard.totalOperationsAlert}}</p>
    ...
  `
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  totalAlertsDashboard: TotalAlertsDashboard;
  alertsDashboard: AlertDashboard[];

  constructor(private alertsDashboardService: AlertsDashboardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.alertsDashboardService.get().then(
      response => {
        this.totalAlertsDashboard = response.totalAlertsDashboard;
        this.alertsDashboard = response.alertsDashboard;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In alerts-dashboard.service.ts I have:

```
...
export class AlertsDashboard {
    totalAlertsDashboard: TotalAlertsDashboard;
    alertsDashboard: AlertDashboard[];
}

export class TotalAlertsDashboard {
    totalOperations: number;
    totalOperationsAlert: number;
    totalOperationsRisk: number;
}

export class AlertDashboard {
    codAlert: string;
    description: string;
    value: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class AlertsDashboardService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private url = environment.urlAPI + '/rest/alertsDashboard';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    get(): Promise<AlertsDashboard> {
        var vm = this;

        let params = new URLSearchParams();

        return vm.http.get(vm.url, { search: params })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            var responseJson: AlertsDashboard = response.json() ;
            console.log(responseJson); // it prints the JSON correctly
            return responseJson;
        });
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Change `totalAlertsDashboard.totalOperations` to `totalAlertsDashboard.total.totalOperations`, etc.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but you should really be using observables instead of promises.

Comment: @TheHeadRush That doesn't work. The console displays: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: co.totalAlertsDashboard is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.alertsDashboardService.get().then(
      response => {
        this.totalAlertsDashboard = response.total;
        this.alertsDashboard = response.alerts;
      }
    );
  }
```

In alerts-dashboard.service.ts

```
export class AlertsDashboard {
    total: TotalAlertsDashboard;
    alerts: AlertDashboard[];
}
```

template :

```
<p>{{totalAlertsDashboard?.totalOperations}}</p>
```

Comment: Not working. It says:
Property 'total' does not exist on type 'AlertasDashboard'.
Property 'alerts' does not exist on type 'AlertasDashboard'

Comment: I updated it. If I add console.log(this.totalAlertsDashboard.totalOperations); it is displayed correctly. But if I try to display it in the template as `<p>{{totalAlertsDashboard.totalOperations}}</p>` the console prints TypeError: co.totalAlertsDashboard is undefined